# LifecycleException Invalid Server SSL Protocol

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, tomcat6

i get an error when i start tomcat. Since 2 days i try to resolve it:

```
LifecycleException:  L'initialisation du gestionnaire de protocole a échoué: java.lang.Exception: Invalid Server SSL Protocol (error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0))
```

For understand, in my server.xml:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />

<Connector 
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystorePass="changed"
       keystoreFile="/home/.keystore"
       SSLCertificateFile="/home/ssl/my.crt" 
       SSLCertificateKeyFile="/home/ssl/my.key"
       SSLPassword="changed"
       SSLVerifyClient="optional"   
       SSLProtocol="TLS"
       protocol="HTTP/1.1" />
```

I create keystore from scratch.

I tried without certificate, change the protocol, without success.

I changed `SSLProtocol` to TLSv1, tomcat give not errors, but my client have an connection reset.

Some help please.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling Apache tomcat's APR by commenting it's listener

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
```

or set it's sslProtocol to

```
protocol = "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
```